# Unity doesn't wake up properly after suspend

Tags: 16.04, unity, nvidia, suspend

After wakeup, more often than not, unity doesn't come up correctly, which results in the login screen being stuck. I can't type in a password, and the only things I can still do to fix it, is either a hard reset, or go to a different terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, and type `unity`.
Then I can switch back to with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> and the login screen works, tho many things are now half working (the top bar doesn't work anymore, keyboard shortcuts don't work anymore, etc.) until I reboot the system.

I am using Ubuntu 16.06 with kernel 4.10.0-40-generic. However, this has been going on with every kernel I've had (always just used the latest available one that `apt` gives me) since I got the laptop, which is October this year.

I'm using proprietary nvidia drivers version 384.90. If I use the nouveau drivers I get way more issues.

[Here's an output](https://pastebin.com/LMpatNtE) of the syslog during the sleep and wake.